# cxf client and service sharing same objects for parameters produces IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

I have created a SOAP web service with CXF, deployed in a war (WAR1).

Also a dynamic client with CXF deployed in another WAR (WAR2).

Both share the same request/response objects packaged in a JAR.

All those are deployed in an EAR.

The service works fine and i can use it via SOAPUI.

When i try to use the service with the dynamic client it gives me a problem.

When i try to use the objects from the JAR to call the service in WAR1, it says the objects are not the same because my request object from the client comes from the jar while the request object that the web service expects in input is from the war.

I get the exception below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://webservice.backend.test.com/}useRequest should be of type com.test.backend.webservice.Request, not com.shared.model.webservice.request.Request
```

Any ideas on what path should i take to track down this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.. You probably have wrong import for the object useRequest. Correct it and redeploy your client... Soap ui generates it's own client and hence is able to work properly. as your webservice as such is fine.

Comment: the thing is the import is the same in both WARS, service and client, as it comes from the same shared JAR.

Comment: Import would be what you declare in the client code..  Can you paste imports of both client and service here..

Comment: both have : import com.shared.model.webservice.request.Request , which is a package of the JAR where i keep shared classes